# Notepad++: How to fold tab text hierarchy and use it as an outline

Tags: notepad++, outline

I love notepad++ but cant find the feature described:
Using a text outline defined by (TAB) as an outline (IE: Being able to fold/collapse based upon that hierarchy)
I found another software that does it (jedit), but I would rather stick to Notepad++ because of its other features.
For more info, this is also discussed and more extensively described here:
http://www.outlinersoftware.com/topics/viewt/4796/5

Can that be done with Notepad++?

Answer (score 10):

When I select `YAML` under the `Language` menu, it seems to work as you describe. You can use tabs to create your hierarchy.